# A sh.exe.stackdump file appeared in the root dir in my app

Tags: git, reactjs, create-react-app

I have a react app created with create-react-app CLI, suddenly a `sh.ext.stackdump` file has appeared in the root directory of my project with the contents

```
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
0022CD28  008ABD26 (00000000, 0022CD84, 007F6D90, 00000000)
End of stack trace
```

Is it a file needed in my application? is it going to break if I delete it? should I keep it? why did it appear?

Comment: Can you check if you have 32-bit git? And are you using a 3rd party console application, such as cmder, conemu?

Comment: To answer your question, the file is a crashdump, so the bash shell crash (sh). I've seen this when using 32-bit git in cmder. Switching to 64-bit and upgrading cmder fixed the problem.

Comment: So is it safe to delete?

Comment: If you don't intend to debug the crash yourself, nor pass the file to someone else who intends to debug the crash, you can simply delete the file.

Comment: Yes, you can delete the file, but be aware that bash did crash. If it was doing something important when it crashed you might have a broken repository.

Comment: Happens for me as well. Seems to be related to problems with authentication when Windows Credentials Manager windows pops up.

Comment: I had basically the same issue, but the file name was bash.exe.stackdump and had the same structure. I just stashed it and finally no more warning about it. Thanks.